# Hyperlinks disappear when hover

Tags: html, css, joomla, hyperlink, hover

I have a problem with some hyperlinks that bug me for couple of days now. On [this site](http://melimpampa.tk)  (Joomla & Virtuemart) that I use [this template](http://demo.joomlashine.com/joomla-templates/jsn_force/pro/index.php) I have four hyperlinks in the upper right hand side (Καλάθι, Σύνδεση, Λογαριασμός & Γνώμες Πελατών) which when I hover them they disappear!

I used the menu icon menu you see on [this template](http://demo.joomlashine.com/joomla-templates/jsn_force/pro/index.php) where you see the Product Tour & Get it now hyperlinks which work well. By looking at the CSS I cannot find why my hyperlinks get the background color when I hover them. My CSS for the specific part is :

```
/* =============== MENU - TOP MENU =============== */
ul.menu-topmenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.menu-topmenu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
ul.menu-topmenu li a {
    padding: 14px 5px;
    color: #999;
    display: block;
}

ul.menu-topmenu li a span {
    display: block;
}
ul.menu-topmenu a:active {
    color: #fff !important;

ul.menu-topmenu a:hover {
    color: #ccc !important;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work even though I used !important word.

Can anyone see how this is happening? 
I thank you in advance

Comment: Check your transition effects, I think in 'green.css' if inspector is correct.

Answer (score 1):

They're not disappearing, they're just changing color. Add this to your CSS:

```
ul.menu-topmenu li a:hover, ul.menu-topmenu li a:active, ul.menu-topmenu li a:focus {
    color: red;
}
```

Chances are also good that your template has a color selector built in. Avoid custom styles whenever possible to reduce development and maintenance effort.

Also, become familiar with your browser's document inspector. It will make troubleshooting this sort of thing simple.

Comment: Your style with work only with !important (i think).

Comment: I thank you very much for your help. I tried what you suggested by putting your code below my css code but that didn't help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @its4yougr add !important. color:red !important;

Comment: If you see my css code it has for hover the !important; word after the color... That also doesn't work....

Comment: I added his code to inspect mode, but also i added !important, and it did worked for me. Try to add span, after a. For example: ul.menu-topmenu li a span:hover { color:red !important; }

Comment: It works only if I add !important at the initial color of the link. I changed my code from ul.menu-topmenu li a {
    padding: 14px 5px;
    color: #999;
    display: block;
} to ul.menu-topmenu li a {
    padding: 14px 5px;
    color: #999 !important;
    display: block;
} but I don't have the hover functionality ! ! ! I might leave it like this... The problem is that it doesn't take the !important; at he hover part...

Comment: You need to forget about `!important` and fix the problem with either file load order or selector specificity. Without knowing more about the CSS files,  I can't be more specific.

Comment: Mr. isherwood I think you are absolutely right. There lots of files that are loaded and this setting goes back and forth... I will set just one color w/o the hover functionality.... I thank you all very much... BR George